# Fuel consumption database using ICAO codes?

Tags: efficiency, datasets, fuel-consumption

I will preface this by saying I do not have any level of knowledge in Aerodynamics - I'm a freelance journalist and so apologies for the poor level of general understanding.

I'm attempting to create a visualisation that would depict CO<sub>2</sub> produced per time in the air per flight, but have not been able to find any comprehensive dataset for average values of fuel consumption per hour per aircraft model.

My goal is to calculate an approximation how much "additional" CO<sub>2</sub> is being emitted by delays.

Most flight calculators I've been able to find give an estimate per person, or per person which tends to evoke distance (https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/CarbonOffset/Pages/default.aspx / https://co2.myclimate.org/en/flight_calculators/new)

Therefore the constants given in the methodologies tend to reflect a fuel consumption per distance in their datatables - which given the fact that the distance travelled overall remains "the same" even if the plane is late doesn't really tell much.

I've attempted to look through the questions here but best thing I've been able to find is a forum post from years ago that isn't comprehensive ([here](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1355819))

I get the feeling I'm missing a source glaringly obvious by not using the correct terminology....

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your linked post looks pretty comprehensive to me.  What major types and models are missing?  If there are specific makes and models not included that you feel contribute a statistically significant amount I would think you could research them individually, or ask here.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, I think what you need is the typical cruise speed of each of the models listed in the other post.  From this you could create a spreadsheet that would give you fuel burn by distance rather than by time, and you could plug in distances of any ICAO airport identifiers to compute the burn on a typical flight between two points by each aircraft type.  Does that get you any closer to what you are looking for?  The math itself is pretty easy, but let us know if you are unsure how to do what I am suggesting.